# Add to compare link is not working on different browers

Tags: magento-1.9

Somehow the link doesn't submit anything...same as the add to cart button

```
<a class="product-actions product-compare" href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>')" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?>"><i class="fa fa-exchange"></i></a>
```

[Site demo](http://www.thewatersshop.com/)

**EDIT:**

I found the answer,  it is because the new "form_key" parameter added to POST requests in Magento to prevent XSS attacks.

The topic [here](https://github.com/nexcess/magento-turpentine/issues/345), you can find the fix at the bottom of the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this problem only occurs in "Google Chrome" I tested in Firefox and it works.

You can test this:

under System -> Configuration -> Web -> Session Validation Settings

Set to “NO” the following:

- Validate REMOTE_ADDR
- Validate HTTP_VIA
- Validate HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR

Comment: Thank you. I fixed that. But  it still doesn't work on my iphone? The add to cart button and add to compare button in the homepage aren't working, but the ones in the product page work?

Comment: You have an error in javascript. The "Add to cart" in category works. But when you are in product view [here](http://www.thewatersshop.com/testing-iphone-5.html) You have an error *Uncaught ReferenceError: productAddToCartForm is not defined*. You have modified the javascript's?

Comment: I think it generates the wrong url or something...If you switch to English on firefox, it works fine but not on chrome, and vice versa. About that button, i forgot to add the script, it should be fixed now. I have Validate HTTP_USER_AGENT and Use SID on Frontend set to YES

Comment: For me now works on iPhone, Firefox and Chrome. I tested also in iPhone/iPad simulator and works in any language and currency.

Comment: I think its fixed now. I refreshed the cache and it only worked only on one browser. If I change the browser, I have to refresh the cache again. I don't know if it has anything to do with security...Thanks a lot btw.